# how to change tuple key into multilevel dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:
d = {key1 : {(key2,key3) : value}, ...}
so it is a dictionary of dictionaries and in the inside dict the keys are tuples.

I would like to get a triple nested dict:
{key1 : {key2 : {key3 : value}, ...}

I know how to do it with 2 loops and a condition:

```
new_d = {}
for key1, inside_dict in d.items():
    new_d[key1] = {}
    for (key2,key3), value in inside_dict.items():
        if key2 in new_d[key1].keys():
            new_d[key1][key2][key3] = value
        else:
            new_d[key1][key2] = {key3 : value}
```

Edit: key2 values are not guaranteed to be unique. This is why I added the condition

It feels very unpythonic to me.
Is there a faster and/or shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the common trick for nesting dicts arbitrarily, using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)  
new_d = tree()

for k1, dct in d.items():
    for (k2, k3), val in dct.items():
        new_d[k1][k2][k3] = val
```

Comment: this is cool, didn't know about this. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, i like this, too. Btw, your original might lose some key3s as you don't update, but replace the innermost dict.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, for this case you can wrap all the looping up in a dict comprehension.  This assumes that your data is unique:

```py
data = {"key1": {("key2", "key3"): "val"}}
{k: {keys[0]: {keys[1]: val}} for k,v in data.items() for keys, val in v.items()}
```

Comment: Edited my question a little bit - the values of key2 are not unique (only the tuple combination)

Comment: This depends on *key1* being unique, but it seems that's not the case. In any case the correct general solution is with defaultdict, but dictionary comprehensions are worth keeping around.